# PHP Symfony createFormBuilder ::add must be of the type string or null, array given

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller, formbuilder

Hy guys!
I develop a webpage with my local webserver (localhost). I use PHP, Symfony, Twig and Doctrine.
When I finished the page where I can go if I press the "New article" button on my homepage and I got that issue (the New Article page will create a New Article in my homepage, therefore I tried to create a form with a formbuilder, I think the in the createFormbuilder method is the wrong piece):

***Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder::add() must be of the type string or null, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\symphart\src\Controller\ArticleController.php***

What's wrong? Anybody any idea?

The ArticleController code:

```
   namespace App\Controller;

   use App\Entity\Article;

   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
   use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

   use Symfony\Components\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
   use Symfony\Components\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
   use Symfony\Components\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

   class ArticleController extends AbstractController {
       /**
        * @Route ("/", name = "article_list")
        * @Method ({"GET"})
        */
       public function index ()
       {
           $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article ::class)->findAll();
           return $this->render('Articles/index.html.twig', array ('articles' => $articles));
       }

       /**
        * @Route ("/article/new", name = "new_article")
        * @Method ({"GET", "POST"})
        */
       public function new (Request $request)
       {
           $article = new Article ();
           $form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
               ->add ('title', TextType::class, array ('attr' => array ('class' => 'form-control')))
               ->add('body'. TextareaType::class, array ('required' => false, 'attr' => array ('class' => 'form-control' )))
               ->add ('save', SubmitType::class, array ('label' => 'Create ', 'attr' => array ('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')))
               ->getForm();

               return $this->render ('articles/new.html.twig', array ('form' => $form->createView()));
       }


       /**
        * @Route ("/article/{id}", name = "article_show")
        */
       public function show ($id)
       {
           $article = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);
           return $this->render ('articles/show.html.twig', array ('article' => $article));
       }

       

       ///**
        //* @Route ("/article/save")
        //*/
       //public function save ()
       //{
       //    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       //    $article = new Article();
       //    $article->setTitle("Article Three");
       //    $article->setBody("This is body for Article Three");

       //    $entityManager->persist($article);

       //    $entityManager->flush();

       //    return new Response ('Saves an article with the id of '. $article->getId());
       //}
   }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a dot after `->add('body'` ;)

Comment: Good eye! Typos are generally not considered to be valid answers on stackoverflow but maybe the poster will come back and accept it.

Comment: @Cerad yeah, but I didn't notice that typo. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error after upgrading `Symfony` from `v4.4` to `v5.4`.

The culprit was: form `getBlockPrefix()` method (that is found in `ExampleType.php` file in `App/From/Type` folder).

Previously returning `null` worked. Yet new version requires returning a `string`

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getBlockPrefix(): string
{
    return '';
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer!!! Not documented anywhere!!! Thanks. I spent a day to find out where is the issue before founding this solution. Thank you.